# How to import fonts in nuxt js

Tags: css, fonts, nuxt.js

I have tried to import fonts in global.css like this:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pixelify+Sans:wght@400..700&display=swap')
However I can’t use the font. Is there a way to import fonts in nuxt?

I expect for the font to be imported correctly. I also don’t want to use libraries like google fonts because that over complicates it

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://github.com/nuxt/fonts You will like the performance of it and ease of use.

Comment: Please add more details to your description. It's not clear how you apply the font in your global.css. Also check your devtools for console error logs and the network tab for loaded fonts.